# Firebase fetchSignInMethodsForEmail not providing phone auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

After user register my app with phone auth, I am having trouble to detect if user exist on firebase. I have set an email address for the user and then call [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#fetchsigninmethodsforemail), but it is not returning phone provider. Do we have any other method that I can use to detect if user has phone auth provider for flutter?

Comment: Did you set an email address for the user after they signed in with their phone number?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes I have email addresses as well for users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebase here*

The `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` function returns the email-based provider that are associated with the account. So if you [link any email-based provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) with the phone-based account it will show up, but you won't ever get back the phone auth provider.

If you need that type of mapping, consider storing it in your own database. It also sounds like a reasonable use-case, just not one the current was meant for, so I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) and Cloud Functions.

```
import { auth } from "firebase-admin";

export const fetchSignInMethods = onCall(async (req) => {
  if (!req.data.email)
    throw new HttpsError("failed-precondition", "A required field is missing.");
  
  const user = await auth().getUserByEmail(req.data.email);
  const methods = user.providerData.map((p) => p.providerId);
  return { methods };
});
```